# What are the main differences from Python and Serpent?

Tags: contract-design, serpent, python

Serpent looks quite similar to Python.  What behaviors or syntax would be on your list to warn other Serpent developers about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While Serpent uses a syntax very similar to Python, there are some important differences to be aware of:

> - Python numbers have potentially unlimited size, Serpent numbers wrap around `2^256`. For example, in Serpent the expression `3^(2^254)` surprisingly evaluates to `1`, even though in reality the actual integer is too large to be recorded in its entirety within the universe.
> - Serpent has no decimals.
> - Serpent has no list comprehensions (expressions like `[x**2 for x in my_list]`), dictionaries or most other advanced features
> - Serpent has no concept of first-class functions. Contracts do have functions, and can call their own functions, but variables (except storage) do not persist across calls.
> - Serpent has a concept of persistent storage variables.
> - Serpent has an extern statement used to call functions from other contracts.
>
> From [Serpent wiki: Differences Between Serpent and Python](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Serpent#differences-between-serpent-and-python)