# What are common pitfalls when coding in Serpent?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, serpent

Some pitfalls for coding in Solidity are [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/305/42) and what kind of pitfalls are there in Serpent?

(This is not related to Python, which is covered [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/307/42))

Answer (score 3):

Serpent has no private methods: all functions are callable externally, which could be exploited to bypass certain input validation or preconditions. The [BTC Relay security Audit](http://martin.swende.se/blog/BTCRelay-Auditing.html#feeless_leeching) revealed such a problem.